# How to show that the computed kernel is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in a simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff

I am working on calculating the first homology group $H_1(X)$ for a simplicial complex
X, and I have found the kernel of the boundary operator $\partial_1: C_1 \rightarrow C_0$ (chain complex) to be the set:

\begin{equation} \{\alpha \cdot [p_0p_1p_2] + \lambda \cdot [p_0p_3p_4]| \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}\} \end{equation}

I understand that to find $H_1(X)=\frac{Ker(\partial_1)}{Im((\partial_2)}$, I need to find the image of $\partial_2$. This is not the problem. However, I want to demonstrate that the kernel I have computed is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Could someone guide me on how to properly show that this kernel is indeed isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$? Specifically, I am thinking of proving that the elements of the set form a basis for the kernel and are linearly independent.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is there to show? Do you mean you want to know why the two triangles are linearly independent? It's in the definition of the chain group.

Comment: @Trebor Yes, you are right. To clarify, I am looking for an isomorphism between the kernel of $\partial_1$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: What does the notation $[p_0 p_1 p_2]$ mean? Is that supposed to be the simplex on three vertices $p_0$, $p_1$, and $p_2$? If it is, then the set you gave cannot be the kernel of $\partial_1$ since it's not a subset of $C_1$ but of $C_2$...

Comment: @BenSteffan Yes it is, because after some calculations, I found $[p_0p_1]+[p_1p_2]+[p_2p_0]$ which is by definition $[p_0p_1p_2]$.

Comment: @Tomleboss First off, there is no simplex $[p_2 p_0]$. If I understand you correctly you should write $[p_1 p_2] - [p_0 p_2] + [p_0 p_1] = \partial [p_0 p_1 p_2]$. Note the $\partial$, because adding three 1-simplices does not somehow automatically constitute a 2-simplex (case in point, there might not even be a 2-simplex with that boundary; think triangle sans interior). I still don't recommend that you write your set as $\{\alpha \cdot \partial [p_0 p_1 p_2] + \beta \cdot \partial [p_0 p_3 p_4] \mid \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ however; it hides what simplices actually appear.

Comment: @BenSteffan No need to be condescending...By definition $[p_0p_2]$ is defined as $-[p_2p_0]$. However, I admit having made a mistake by forgetting the $\partial$, but this doesn't help me to prove the isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: @Tomleboss I am not trying to be condescending, just pointing out basic issues. I am recommending you write these things out according to definition because it ties in directly with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the issues pointed out in the comments assumed fixed, let $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\varphi\colon \Z^2 \to \ker(\partial_1)$ be the map $\varphi(a, b) = a \cdot ([p_1 p_2] - [p_0 p_2] + [p_0 p_1]) + b \cdot ([p_3 p_4] - [p_0 p_4] + [p_0 p_3])$. It is surjective by definition and injective since
$$
    a \cdot ([p_1 p_2] - [p_0 p_2] + [p_0 p_1]) = b \cdot ([p_3 p_4] - [p_0 p_4] + [p_0 p_3])
$$
is to say that
$$
    a \cdot [p_1 p_2] = b \cdot ([p_3 p_4] - [p_0 p_4] + [p_0 p_3]) + a \cdot ([p_0 p_2] - [p_0 p_1])
$$
the only solution to which is $a = b = 0$ since by definition the 1-simplices form a basis of $C_1$ and are therefore in particular linearly independent.

In other words, $\varphi$ is the (/an) isomorphism you want.

Comment: Thank you. For injectivity, you could also use that $\phi(a,b)=\phi(c,d) \Rightarrow (a,b)=(c,d)$, which is trivial as coefficients have to be the same.

Comment: @Tomleboss Well, yes, but only if you know that $\varphi(a, 0)$ and $\varphi(0, b)$ are linearly independent, which was to be shown.